# Is there any way to see the present power consumption rate in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way that can notify the user the battery consumption rate in Android. 
What I want to get :

a) An application showing Power consumption rate by each running application.
b) Power consumption by each process in an application.

Initial search says that it may be possible using ndk with  a constraint of not being achieving the accuracy.

I am more interested in the sample code, workflow to achieve the target.

Any valid input / suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: This question was posted 3 years back. Still no answer? As suggested in the accepted answer? I have already seen those posts, after going through those, I am posting again as none have the valid answer. One says not possible (3 years back).

Comment: It's still a duplicate since one of the answers has the correct and valid answer to your question. We are not allowed to plagiarize others' answers, so it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Under */frameworks/base/core/res/res/xml/power_profile.xml* (which you can acquire by grabbing the frameworks jar from the actual device) there is a list of values with their specified features.

Using this file you can for example acquire the power consumption values for different CPU speeds, or different modules (bluetooth, wifi, etc), along with the battery capacity. That's how system measures consumption per process. However please mind that there is also way more to it, including historical data, and other variables.

To perform precise measurements you would need to perform a system trace (systrace tool), parse the output, assign values from the power_profile to each system process, and then approximate the consumption... but:

1) The task is non-trivial

2) There is a lot of system specific features which you cannot even begin to measure. You would have to only rely on cpu speeds, ex. if app A was active, then read the cpu speed, and calculate the total consumption for that period.

3) It's still an approximation

4) Works per device (**strictly**, even identically named devices can have different consumption due to minor components differences applied over its market life time)

5) Cannot be done on the device, unless you can compact the mentioned process.

6) You have to rely on the device maker - it's not 100% assured that the power_profile values are correct.

**UPDATE**
Apparently someone made [syspower library] which from the first look should provide some info on battery consumption. Unfortunately it's doesn't look like it's production ready.[1](https://code.google.com/p/syspower/)

Comment: I can see, the description is correct. So it is totally depends on the OEM. Still the question was to find the battery usage by an application. That file contains details of audio, video, radio, gps, screen and not for an application. Thanks for the input.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power.html